# az login with certificate protected with password

Tags: azure-cli

I was told to use Azure service principal with auth by certificate which is protected by password
I'm trying to login with az cli: `az login --service-principal --username '$APP_ID' --tenant '$TENANT_ID' --password C:\sda-cript-dvlp.pfx`
..obviously there're no cert password and login fails

Where should I paste certificate's password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sign in with a certificate, it must be available locally as a `PEM` or `DER` file, in `ASCII` format. When using a `PEM` file, the `PRIVATE KEY` and `CERTIFICATE` must be appended together within the file.

You could refer to the steps below.

1.Login with a user(need the permission to create a service principal), create a service principal along with a self-signed certificate.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name 'joyapp234' --create-cert
```

[image]

2.Copy the `fileWithCertAndPrivateKey` in step 1, login as below.

```
az login --service-principal --username '<app-id>' --tenant '<tenant-id>' --password 'C:\\Users\\joyw\\tmpbnpcixh8.pem'
```

[image]

For more details, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#certificate-based-authentication) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#sign-in-using-a-service-principal).