# AZ copy File transfer issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azcopy

I am facing issue in copying files from Edgenode to ADLS. For this i used AZCOPY and here is the code for that. It ran perfectly fine in Dev environment.

When it comes to the test environment it behaves odd,

```
    export AZCOPY_AUTO_LOGIN_TYPE="SPN"
    export AZCOPY_SPA_APPLICATION_ID="$client_id"
    export AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET="$client_secret"
    export AZCOPY_TENANT_ID="$tenant_id"
    az login --service-principal -u $client_id --tenant $tenant_id -p $client_secret
```

Azcopy code
azcopy cp --overwrite "True" "$src_file_path" "$dest_file_path" --put-md5

and the error snipped which I am getting in test environment is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a0nI.png)

Any suggestions or solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

The **`403 unauthorized`** error usually occurs if you don't have required permissions/roles to perform the action.

To resolve the error, try assigning **`Storage Blob Data Owner`** or **`Storage Blob Data Contributor`** role to your storage account.

[image]

**Confirm whether the roles are assigned or not by following below:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active directory -> Users -> Select user -> Azure role assignment*

[image]

**Reference:**

[What is the best way to transfer huge files to Azure Data Lake Storage? (nealanalytics.com)](https://nealanalytics.com/blog/what-is-the-best-way-to-transfer-huge-files-to-azure-data-lake-storage/)

[azure cli - az login with certificate protected with password - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477714/az-login-with-certificate-protected-with-password)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the IAM control set correctly and if the storage account is restricted to connect from specific networks only then you need to add your IP address to the access list.

*Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Account -> Networking -> Click on Add you IP address -> Hit Save*
This should help you fix the error.